# Meteor publish and subscribe not working on accessing data on aldeed:tabular

Tags: meteor

I have some problems with meteor publish and subscribe.

well in my code, as usual I used meteor publish and subscribe, but it seems its not working when Meteor.publish is trying to access the collection that is already in aldeed:tabular. here is my code

on server :

```
Meteor.publish("direktoratList", function(){
    return mstTblDept.find();
});

Meteor.publish("piutangData", function(){
    return tblPiutang.find();
});

Meteor.publish("budgetData", function(){
    return tblBudget.find();
});
```

On Client

```
Meteor.subscribe("direktoratList");
var dataFind1 = mstTblDept.find().fetch();

Meteor.subscribe("piutangData");
var dataFind2 = tblPiutang.find().fetch();

Meteor.subscribe("budgetData");
var dataFind3 = tblBudget.find().fetch();
```

and in my common folder (works in client and server)

```
tblBudget = new Meteor.Collection("TBLBUDGET");
mstTblDept = new Meteor.Collection("MSTTBLDEPT");
tblPiutang = new Meteor.Collection("TBLPIUTANG");
```

Well, `aldeed:tabular` is using tblBudget and tblPiutang collection.
when I tried to look in console, the length of dataFind2, and dataFind3 is zero (0) which is also a collection in `aldeed:tabular`but the length of dataFind1 is not zero and it catch the data from the collection.

Am I do this wrong?? really appreciate the help :)

Comment: aldeed:Tabular handles the subscriptions for you you don't have to publish or subscribe to any data, It's possible it's screwing up the other publishing you might take a look at the project's github issues tab maybe somebody faced the same issue

Comment: Can we have your tabular script please?

Comment: `TabularTables.Budget = new Tabular.Table({
   name: "BudgetList",
   collection: tblBudget,
 autoWidth:true,
   columns: [
 {data: "_id", title:"ID", visible:false},
     {data: "tahun", title: "Tahun", visible:true, width:"3%"},
     {data: "bulan", title: "Bulan", visible:true,width:"3%"},
     {data: "kodecab", title: "Cabang", width:"10%"},
 {data: "kodedept", title: "Dir Code", width:"10%", visible:false},
 {data: "deptname", title: "Dept", width:"10%", visible:false}
   ]
});`

thats the tabular script